# Julia: How to obtain the names of a NamedTuple?

Tags: julia

For example,

```
nt = (a=1,b="b",c=5.0)
```

How do I get the names of `nt` which are `[:a,:b,:c]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for any other key-value structure (like a dictionary), you can use the `keys` function:

```
julia> nt = (a=1,b="b",c=5.0)
(a = 1, b = "b", c = 5.0)

julia> keys(nt)
(:a, :b, :c)
```

Note that in general this returns an iterator over the keys. If you really want to materialize it `collect` the result:

```
julia> collect(keys(nt))
3-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :a
 :b
 :c
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `names` are Julia symbols (that's what the leading colon signifies).  If you want the names to be strings rather than symbols, construct the strings from the collected keys.

```
 julia> nt = (two = 2, three = 3)
 (two = 2, three = 3)

 julia> namestrs = String.collect(keys(nt))
 2-element Array(String,1):
  "two"
  "three"
```